# Change System Volume in WinRT

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, windows-runtime, volume

I have a volume slider in my WinRT app which I would like to sync with the system volume. Is there a way to do this? iOS allows developers to give this functionality.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The volume of playback can be controlled using the [MediaElement.Volume](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.mediaelement.volume) property. I cannot find a specific supporting quote but my own observations indicate the volume is per MediaElement object [like it is in SilverLight](http://forums.silverlight.net/t/13034.aspx/1) and there is no way to change the system volume in an app.

Answer (score 2):

The volume of playback can be controlled using the MediaElement.Volume property
as this property is a double value between 0 and 1.

You can use a slider to control the volume in this case you do:

```
private void slider_ValueChanged(object sender, RangeBaseValueChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if(mute)
    {
        MediaElement.IsMuted = false;
        mute = false;
        MediaElement.Volume = (slider.Value)/100;
    }
    else
    {
        MediaElement.Volume = (slider.Value) / 100;
    }
}
```

The mute variable is of Boolean data-type that controls whether the sound is cut or not